# Replacing EJBs on application server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

There is a J2EE application server running with some applications deployed containing EJBs remotely called by clients.

Is there any way how other application deployed on the same server can "override" the EJBs and replace them with some mocks? Or at least intercept the calls? (Does not need to be in runtime, deploy time is enough.)

I have some ideas how to do it but I do not know how to proceed or where I should start:

1. Can I replace the JNDI lookup service of application server with some custom implementation which provides mocks while injecting EJBs to applications while deploying?
2. Should I use aspects on EJBs?

The solution should be generic, but will be happy if it works at least on one of Weblogic, Glassfish or JBoss.

Comment: You can play with application server management API and try to unregister deployed EJBs from JNDI and register your mocks with same name. But this is absolutely vendor-specific task, so please describe what application server do you use.

Comment: The solution has to run on Websphere.